# which thread finished first in concurrent threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new in concurrent threads in java. I am trying to code a simple horse race simulation.

I want to know which thread finished first.
This code below throws an error: incompatible types: Thread cannot be converted to Gate

```
winner = (Gate)Thread.currentThread();
```

**Gate.java**

```
public class Gate implements Runnable{
    public String horseName;
    public final int GATE_DISTANCE = 20;
    public final int FINISH_LINE_DISTANCE = 100;
    public CyclicBarrier barrier;

    public Gate(CyclicBarrier barrier,String horseName){
        this.horseName = horseName;
        this.barrier = barrier;
    }

    public void run(){
        //Walk all horses to respective racing gates before starting race
        for(int distanceCovered = 0; distanceCovered < GATE_DISTANCE;){
            distanceCovered += gallop();
            int distanceLeft = GATE_DISTANCE - distanceCovered;
            if(distanceLeft < 0){
                distanceLeft = 0;               
            }
            System.out.println(horseName + "\t\tgate distance left " + distanceLeft);
            if(distanceLeft == 0){
                break;
            }
        }

        //Wait for all horses to be at racing gates
        try{
            barrier.await();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie){
            System.out.println("INTERRUPTED");
        }
        catch(BrokenBarrierException bbe){
            System.out.println("BROKEN");
        }

        //ACTUAL HORSE RACE
        for(int distanceCovered = 0; distanceCovered < FINISH_LINE_DISTANCE;){
            distanceCovered += gallop();
            int distanceLeft = FINISH_LINE_DISTANCE - distanceCovered;
            if(distanceLeft < 0){
                distanceLeft = 0;               
            }
            System.out.println(horseName + "\t\tgate distance left " + distanceLeft);
            if(distanceLeft == 0){
                break;
            }
        }   

        Main.done();
    }   

    public int gallop(){
        final int MIN_GALLOP = 1,
                        MAX_GALLOP = 10;

        Random random = new Random();   
        int gallopRange = MAX_GALLOP - MIN_GALLOP + 1;  
        int totalGallop = random.nextInt(gallopRange) + MIN_GALLOP; 
        return totalGallop;
    }   
}
```

**GateMain.java**

```
public class GateMain{
    private static Gate winner = null;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int horseCount = 5;

        List<String> horseNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Thread> RG = new ArrayList<Thread>();

        horseNames.add("Red Bullet");
        horseNames.add("Green Furious");
        horseNames.add("Pink Mirage");
        horseNames.add("Blue Dash");
        horseNames.add("Yellow Burst");     

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        final CyclicBarrier cb = new CyclicBarrier(horseCount,new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                System.out.print("\nALL HORSES ARE IN THEIR RESPECTIVE RACING GATES");
                System.out.println("\nRACE BEGIN!!!\n");
            }
        });

        for(int horseCtr = 0; horseCtr < horseCount; horseCtr++){
            Gate rg = new Gate(cb,horseNames.get(horseCtr));            
            Thread thread = new Thread(rg);
            thread.start();

            RG.add(thread);
        }

        for(Thread thread: RG){
            try{
                thread.join();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ie){
                System.out.println("Thread Interrupted");
            }           
        }
        System.out.println(winner.horseName + "\t\t\twins!");
    }

    synchronized static void done(){
        if(winner == null){
            winner = (Gate)Thread.currentThread();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a global `AtomicInteger`.

```
public static AtomicInteger finishLine = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

Each horse (thread) should have its own `place` variable,

```
int place;
```

and when a horse finishes the race, it sets its own place:

```
place = finishLine.incrementAndGet();
```

The first horse to reach the finish line will get `place=1`, the second horse, `place=2`, and so on.  Then the `main()` routine must then examine each horse to find out which one has `place=1`.  That'll be the winner.

---

Here's a different idea, inspired by the finish-line of a cross-country foot race: Instead of an AtomicInteger, use a thread-safe queue.

```
public static ArrayBlockingQueue<Horse> chute =
    new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(NUMBER_OF_HORSES);
```

When each horse reaches the finish line, it enters the chute.

```
chute.add(this);
```

This way, there is no need to explicitly wait for the race to end, and there is no need to explicitly sort the finishers:

```
Horse win = chute.take();    //waits for the first horse to finish
Horse place = chute.take();  //waits for the second horse
Horse show = chute.take();   //...
```

Comment: even though I am not convinced about merit of this question, I like the answer.

Answer (score 1):

However, just synchronizing here will not work, according to the rules of Java. You have to synchronize the update that you want the thread to read, as well. Depending on what variable is, that may or may not be a problem.

You may need to think out your threading model a bit more, and describe here what you want to do. If you were unaware of mutual exclusion, you may not be ready to design threaded code.

if you're trying to access an instance field from a static member, I have to wonder how you got the code to compile.

Thread.currentThread() returns the actual Thread object you (or some other library code) created. That can be a Gate thread, but it all depends on the Thread object it is running in. Safest is to use instanceof to check first.

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread--) `Thread.currentThread()` returns a reference to the current thread, not the object. So, you should look for reference to the object i.e [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) keyword.

You wish to have `winner` as a private member. You can't change it from run() in another class. So, you can pass the current object from `run()` as an argument to a method in `GateMain` by `this`.

You can edit the `done()` method as:

```
synchronized static void done(Gate new_gate){
    if(winner == null){
        winner = new_gate;
    }
}
```

Replace the line `Main.done()` with `Main.done(this)`

Comment: I'd suggest to replace type of `Main.winner` to`AtomicReference<Gate>` thus you can make call `Main.winner.compareAndSet(null, new_gate)` and remove `syncronized`.

Comment: You can change type of Main.winner to  AtomicReference<Gate> to avoid `synchronized` but you can't make `Main.winner` public. You must have to change winner from `Main class` itself.

Comment: I didn't say anything about making the field public. It's static, so `Main.winner` is acceptable in `Main.done`.

Comment: Now I get it. When you were referring to `Main.winner` I thought you were accessing `winner` object in `Main` class. You actually did it for clarity. Right?? You too want `done` to be in `Main` class itself.

Comment: Yes. Method `done` is in `Main`, hiding direct access to winner.